# RecylcerView item click listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to capture the on click event of the items in my RecyclerView, but it isn't working. My research (SO) told me to put the listener in the adapter, so I did. Here's the code :

```
    public class PoliticianPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoliticianPagerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private Politician[] mDataset;

        // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
        // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
        // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
        public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            // each data item is just a string in this case
            public TextView name;
            public TextView term;
            public TextView position;
            public ImageView image;
            public CardView card ;
            public ViewHolder(View layout) {
                super(layout);
                name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.politicianNameAndParty);
                term = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.politicianTerm);
                position = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.politicianPosition);
                image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.politicianImage);
                card = (CardView) layout.findViewById(R.id.politicianCard);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),PoliticianPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        }

        public PoliticianPagerAdapter(Politician[] myDataset) {
            mDataset = myDataset;
        }

        @Override
        public PoliticianPagerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_politician_block, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(v);

        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            holder.name.setText(mDataset[position].name + " (" + mDataset[position].party + ")");
            holder.term.setText(Integer.toString(mDataset[position].termBegin) + " - " + Integer.toString(mDataset[position].termEnd));
            holder.term.setText(mDataset[position].position);
            holder.image.setImageResource(mDataset[position].image);


        }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataset.length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a View inside the CardView to intercept the click event.

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <!-- Your card -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/clickable_view_card"
            android:clickable="true"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
 public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public RelativeLayout clickable_layout;



            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                clickable_layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clickable_view_card);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.clickable_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("OnClick", "position clicked: "+ position);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver :) Can you explain the reason this works, but the solution that I've seen everywhere else online doesn't? I'm assuming my case is different from the others, but what makes it so? Anyway, thanks so much! @VictorBG

Comment: The most solutions is to capture the click event with the MotionEvent but when you have views that are clickables apart from the card this doesn't work because you capture the click event in ALL of the card. Using a View, in this case RelativeLayout, inside the CardView and setting it clickable you can add another views with their clickables methods in the Card like Buttons and intercept the clicks separately, but you can't put clickables views inside another view that is clickable.